# Accessing OSX files and folders from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I would like to dual boot ubuntu 12.04 and OSX Lion. Is there a way that I can access all my music, documents, etc. from my ubuntu partition?

Comment: Yes, you double click on the Mac OS X partition and browse your files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to read the OSX partition from Ubuntu without any modifications. You might have to mount the partition, although I would expect Ubuntu to automatically mount it read only, so you just have to find the partition in the file browser and open it.

OSX by default uses journaled HFS+ as it's file system. Ubuntus kernel has support for this file system built in. If you want read/write access to the OSX partition, you have to disable journaling in OSX. Here are some guides with more details:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/hfsplus
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man7/hfsplus.7.html

Note that I would not recommend disabling journaling, and I do not recommend writing to the OSX system partition from a different OS. If you want to read and write to some files from both OSs, you should create a separate partition for this purpose. Non-journaled HFS+ would work as a file system, FAT 32 should also work.

Comment: Be careful: The hfsplus package is several years outdated. It only support HFS+ volumes with Apple Partition Maps, NOT GUID tables. i.e., it doesn't support Intel Macs.